# "It's years since" + simple past / present perfect

Tags: grammar

Many would not be guided which to use, or which indeed, is the correct usage as well as I am myself.

Should it be the past simple or the present perfect?

> It's ( it is ) years since I saw her. / It's years since I have seen her.

I know Since = conjunction when it is followed by a simple past and since = preposition when it is followed by a present perfect tense. However, this does not solve such issue of grammar whether since is a preposition or a conjunction.
**Sorry** :  I was hurried and did not look my words carefully.. For part 2  = preposition = normally with present perfect .... I haven't seen him since Monday.  Not I didn't see him since Monday.

On the other hand, many would say that "since" is not used with the simple past. For me, I see it is a wrong idea. I know "since" is definitely used when there is apparently starting point, for example, "since 2002", "since 10 April", "since January", "since his birthday", etc.

Comment: In both cases the main clause would need to be "It has been years since..." or "It's been years since...".

Comment: I feel like "It's *been* years since..." would also be more often heard in common parlance, at least in the USA.

Comment: One major problem with how many people form English sentences is that they will begin the sentence with an assumed "it" which cannot be properly defined or described. One great example is the following: "It is raining outside". What is _It_? What is raining? In this case, confusion is born from the use of "It" at the beginning. A more proper way to form this sentence would be "I have not seen her in years".

Comment: @BlueDev - your comment serves only to confuse, since the dummy "it," including the one in "it's raining" or "it's been years since...", is in very common use as an essential part of the language and is not a problem, let alone a major problem.

Comment: @Julien - [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+is+years+since%2Cit+has+been+years+since&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) shows that _it has been years since_ has overtaken _it is years since_, but, as you say, much more strongly in the USA. (As a BrE speaker, I find "It's years since I've seen her" entirely natural.)

Comment: @cruthers I would argue that it is in no way an essential part of the English language, as there is always at least 1 way to say the same thing in a more precise way that is also grammatically correct and easily grammatically explainable. The use of a vague "it" (that cannot be defined) as the subject of a sentence has been ridiculed by many grammar specialists I have known throughout my life. Please give an example showing how this is in any way an essential part of the English language.

Comment: @BlueDev - You gave one yourself - "it's raining."

Comment: @cruthers So I wrote out a full comment on this before I suddenly defined what dozens of English teachers have ridiculed and been unable to explain. 
"It is raining". The clouds are raining down water on us. The clouds are raining, the object (water) is assumed, just as the subject is. It sounds simple once written out, but literally not a single English major throughout my life was ever able to explain that. 

On another note, this shows that every instance of "raining" does require an object which is _being rained_, even if it is assumed/omitted.
+1 your comment for directing me.

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect:

> I know Since = conjunction when it is followed by a simple past and since = preposition when it is followed by a present perfect tense

In fact, "since" is a subordinating conjunction in both of your examples and may in general be followed by either the simple past or present perfect.

We generally use the simple past when a specific time is indicated and the present perfect otherwise. Your example is an ambiguous case, because no time is explicitly mentioned but a specific time is implied (i.e., the time at which the speaker last saw her). Therefore, either version would be acceptable, and both sound natural.

As indicated in the comments, many people (though certainly not all) would prefer that the matrix clause be in the present perfect:

> It's been years since I saw her.
> It's been years since I have seen her.

Comment: Isn't there always an implied specific time?

Comment: @Andrew No. For example: "I have never been to Brazil." No specific time is implied.

Comment: Sorry, I mean with "since"

Comment: @Andrew I believe so, due to the meaning of "since". It means after some time in the past, and that time is generally specific. Nevertheless, there are some gray areas, e.g. "I've been very lonely since you've been gone." (One wouldn't normally say "I've been very lonely since you were gone.") However, I'd say that that "since" uses a different justification for the present perfect (i.e., action that began in the past and continues until the present).

Answer (score 0):

As much as I read books, I noticed both It is years + since + past simple many books mentioned..   However, for it is years + since + present perfect, the much used, is  It has been years

Examples  and explanation:

### It has been five years since I have seen him. ( implies I haven't seen him   for five years.
It's five years since I had my accident. ( the present perfect is not acceptable here ) because the idea can be interpreted as :  I had the accident five years ago and I might have had that accident at any time since then.

For the user who replied saying :  This is incorrect:

I know Since = conjunction when it is followed by a simple past and since = preposition when it is followed by a present perfect tense

**Sorry** :  I was hurried and did not look my words carefully.. For part 2  = preposition = normally with present perfect .... I haven't seen him since Monday.  Not I didn't see him since Monday.

I just upload the following notice from one book of grammar.

By the way, this is not the only grammar book which mentioned the same idea.
[image]