Another view of since
I searched and found this explanation,
"It's five years since I had my accident. ( the present perfect is not acceptable here ) because the idea can be interpreted as : I had the accident five years ago and I might have had that accident at any time since then."
According to explanation I had  realized that if i use present perfect tense that would mean "might have happened that action at any time since then." So I had started thinking present perfect simple, it means started in the past and continues to the present.What I had got understood that present perfect tense still having ability to do, so the action expressed in a sentence is can happen now because it is used for permanent. Thats why I had assumed that view to understand the meaning "it is five years since I had my accident."  But I had continued thinking, how about it would be if I use that view in the following sentences,
1.It has been 6 months since my brother passed away.(Normally I use since but according to explanation pass away might have happened at any time since then,hence the sentence would be not acceptable because noone can't die next time after dying ,thats why i should not use this sentence although the sentence is grammaritically)
#1.It is 6 months since my brother passed away.(According to explanation, a man can't die next time after dying that might not have happened at any time since then.)
Therefore I want to more use "It is 6 months since my brother passed away" than "It has been 6 months since my brother passed away."
2.It has been 3 years since I bought a new car.(Normally I use the perfect tense, but I might have bought that car at any time since then ,the meaning  would be I might have bought a car that I have already bought.The meaning would be not acceptable but sentence is grammatically correct though)
#2.It is 3 years since I bought a new car.(According to explanation,I bought a new car and there is no need that view  that  I might have bought that car at any time since then)
Finally, I want to say that I assumed that "it is five years since I were in London" is used above explanation. i will specify that view as another view of since .I will use only perfect tenses for since because there is the rule in Google that since can be used only perfect tenses.However, if some one use present simple "it is .....since" then I will understand that they are using another view of since.
Is it correct? Please I need to be correct.

You don't say where you found the 'explanation', but it isn't a very good one.
It is five years since I had my accident uses the simple past tense to refer to a single event that happened five years ago.
We would use the present perfect to refer to something you have probably done a number of times in the past. It is five years since I have seen her (you used to see her regularly before that last time). It is a long time since I have eaten roast beef (but I used to eat it more often at one time).
I don't think it makes any difference whether you say It is five years since... or It has been five years since...

I accept your answer, in my answer I wanted to point that it is five years since,because I kept in mind for usage of since that  should be it has been five years since. Perfect tenses and past simple are followed after since , yes I know that, what makes me confused is that it is five years since form and it is a long time since form.According as your answer,it does not make any difference whether I  use it is five years since or I use it has been five years since those are same. Now I keep in mind.Thank you madam for being patient and taking care of my question @Kate Bunting.

Incidentally, I found this explanation in this site and here it is, https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/319268/its-years-since-simple-past-present-perfect @Kate Bunting

Thamilay, you should have posted that link in your original question. Note that the person who wrote that was answering his own question, and his answer did not receive any upvotes. I recommend that you ignore it.

Yes,madam. I will obey.@Kate Bunting
